# How do I download a tarball of source code in fisheye?

Tags: atlassian-fisheye

Within fisheye, I see where you configure a repository to allow for download of source code as a tarball, but I do not see where you go within fisheye to actually download the tarball?  Where is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are few steps to ensure that you have your FishEye configured properly for this.
(I'm using FishEye 3.0.1, but the procedure should be the same in older versions)

---

**Step 1:**

Check `Allow users to download repository trees as tarballs` on `/admin/admin.do#repositorydefaults-tarballs`:

[image]

These are only default settings and will allow all repositories created after this to be downloaded as tarballs.

---

**Step 2:**

Ensure that your current repository (the one that you want to download) either using default settings or has tarballs enabled on `/admin/admin.do#repositories-view-<your_repo>`, section `Tarballs`:

[image]

---

**Step 3:**

Go to `/browse/<your_repo>`. There should now be a link `Download archive`:

[image]

Hope this helps.